# Can't interact with anything inside UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to create a vertical scrollView that is made up of a stack view with three subviews. The top two are working great but I can't interact with the button or search bar that are embedded in the third view. I also can't vertically scroll the scrollView but I'm thinking that is because of the issue interacting with my third subview. Here is what my scene hierarchy looks like with constraints.

Notice the stack view has a UIView called totemView that works as well as a horizontally scrolling collectionView that also works. It's the Events View that I can't interact with. (Full disclosure this is my first app)

[Scene Hierarchy][2]

EDIT: I've tried setting the user interaction to true and false for the Event View but neither works. My view frames sizes and y values are set as follows:

Super View is 414 x 896, y is 0 
  Vertical Scroll View is 414 x 769, y is 44 
    Stack View is 414 x 1224, y is 44 
      Event View is 414 x 768, y is 348 (below other two views in stack)

Comment: A common cause of this is when a view's frame lies outside of its parent's bounds.  Another is userInteraction set to false, which is the default for things like image views

Comment: @danh - Thanks for the suggestion! I tried setting userInteraction to false but it still didn't work. I just added my frame sizes and y positions to the post. I don't believe my frame lies outside of any parent views but since my stack view is embedded in a vertical scroll view, I'm not sure if the lower bounds matters. As you can see from my constraints in the photo, my stack view is constrained to the Content Layout Guide and the Event View is constrained to the super view which i think in this case refers to teh stack view.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I had to set my stack view height constraint to equal the frame layout guide and change the priority to 250.